# How to get Nvidia 555M working on Ubuntu 12.10 (drivers, optimus, cuda)?

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, cuda

I'm trying for few days to get my GPU working properly on Alienware M14x with GPU NVidia 555M, but I have no luck at all.
After fresh ubuntu install I did follow the guide here [NVIDIA Optimus and Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203400/nvidia-optimus-and-ubuntu-12-10) and istalled Bumblebee without problems. Tested `glxspheres/optirun glxspheres` both working fine. Now I was continuing to install CUDA as is said here [How can I get nVidia CUDA or OpenCL working on a laptop with nVidia discrete card/Intel Integrated Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131506/how-can-i-get-nvidia-cuda-or-opencl-working-on-a-laptop-with-nvidia-discrete-car?rq=1) but I'm getting:

```
Driver:   Not Selected
Toolkit:  Installation Failed. Using unsupported Compiler.
Samples:  Installation Failed. Missing required libraries.
```

I did not select the driver as I though Bumblebee installed driver already. How should I proceed?
And also at what point is the NVidia driver being installed and how can I try its working? Bumblebee seems to be installing the driver, CUDA wants to do the same, its all a bit confusing really.

Sorry if its lame question, but I would really want to at least get graphic card and second screen working..

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the Toolkit problem, make sure you are using gcc version 4.6. You can sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6 and then

```
    sudo mv /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 /usr/bin/gcc
```

(To un-do this afterwards, you can move the other one back). There may be some way to do this with options to the CUDA installer, but I can't figure it out.

To fix the Samples problem, you can put a link to where it is expected:

```
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so /usr/lib/libglut.so
```

Answer (score 0):

The flag `-override compiler` can be used to suppress the error message about the compiler being unsupported.

```
./cuda_5.0.35_linux_64_ubuntu11.10-1.run  -override compiler
```

For me, that also got rid of the glut lib error.