# Problems running Unity and graphical applications with Nvidia Optimus

Tags: nvidia-optimus

I'm having a lot of trouble getting Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running smoothly on my laptop. The computer has Nvidia Optimus, with an integrated HD4000 and a discrete Nvidia GTX 765M.

Initially I was just getting a black screen on startup; I installed Bumblebee and can now get to the desktop if I add the `nomodeset` argument (nomodeset didn't work by itself without bumblebee). Now:

1) Unity doesn't start, and trying to open it manually gives me errors;

2) Additional Drivers says that the Nvidia graphics driver is activated but not in use;

3) Trying to run `glxgears` or `glxspheres` gives me this error:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

4) Trying to run 'optirun glxgears` gives me this error:

```
[ 2028.461627] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please

[ 2028.461673] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

I've spent all day reading through posts about problems with Optimus, but nothing so far has helped.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks. There's a whole host of similar questions about Optimus here, but the solutions didn't help me, and I'm hoping that my specific error messages might help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error:

Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual

But **optirun glxgear** works now. I've done it like this: [How to install nvidia optimus driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202644/how-to-install-nvidia-optimus-driver-on-ubuntu-12-10)