# Bumblebee's optirun command was working fine, then suddenly it does nothing anymore

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I installed Bumblebee today on my Dell laptop (i3 2370 + GF630M) to play Doom, using Doomsday. I tested the "optirun" command with firefox, then with doomsday and all was working fine. Now however, when I type "optirun doomsday" or "optirun firefox" in the terminal, literally nothing happens. No error message, the process just hangs for eternity, unless I terminate it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, due to Linux headers not working properly. A previous [answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202644/how-to-install-nvidia-optimus-driver-on-ubuntu-12-10) suggested (also the info on the bumblebee homepage) to install:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo apt-get purge bbswitch-dkms bumblebee-nvidia
```

That installs the PPA-Purge utility and removes BBSwitch and Bumblebee. Then

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

installs the proper Linux headers. In my case, however, I had to use:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) && sudo dkms autoinstall && sudo restart bumblebeed
```

Since it seems the "generic headers" weren't enough in my case. Finally

```
sudo apt-get install bbswitch-dkms bumblebee-nvidia
```

But, if you are using Ubuntu 13.10 there might be a further issue, as explained by [this post](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/fix-bumblebee-libturbojpegso-issue-in.html):

> In Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander), it seems that the libturbojpeg .so
>   filename has changed from libturbojpeg.so to libturbojpeg.so.0 and
>   this breaks Bumblebee.

The way to fix it (for 32bit) is to run the following:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libturbojpeg.so.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libturbojpeg.so
```

See [the post itself](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/fix-bumblebee-libturbojpegso-issue-in.html) for the 64 bit version

I hope this solves your issue, let me know how you get on.

Comment: No luck. After following the steps you suggested, bumblebee doesn't work at all anymore. I get this error everytime I try to optirun something:

Comment: Application terminated due to exception:
(GLTarget::validate) Unsupported
ResourceSystem: All GL textures for RawTextures deleted.
Texture-based framebuffer failed:
  [ConfigError] (GLTarget::validate) Unsupported
Trying fallback without depth/stencil texture
(GLTarget::validate) Unsupported
primus: warning: glXSwapBuffers: no current context
primus: warning: glXSwapBuffers: no current context
primus: warning: glXSwapBuffers: no current context
GLState: Current target destroyed, clearing pointer 
Restoring original display mode due to shutdown.
Canvas: Lost focus.
Shutting down the console...

Comment: Also, even before I tried fixing bumblebee, I started getting "System problem detected" messages at startup and during using Ubuntu.

Sorry for the doublepost, but there's a character limit. :|

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know what it could be. Perhaps someone else will be able to provide an answer, sorry I couldn't help.